# Determining wether SPContentType and SPField are created by user or not

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, custom, spfield

I am doing a migration tool (web part) that copies a site collection from point a to point b. Everything works so far, but currently only custom lists are copied to point b. Now I need a way to determine if a content type and a field are created by the user or not and then add them to each list being created.

Can anybody help me out here? Thanks!

EDIT: BTW, I have already found something but I don't know if it is sufficient for my needs. What I'm not sure about is if `SPField.FromBaseType` will work 100% of the time for my needs.

Comment: I'm working on something similar, did you find a way to do this?